# Limit how much times directive executes the method

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I have a list of buttons that route to various links:

```
<li nz-menu-item [nzSelected]="isSelected('/home')" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
  <span title><i nz-icon type="home"></i>Home</span>
</li>
<li nz-menu-item [nzSelected]="isSelected('/news')" routerLink="/news" routerLinkActive="active">
  <span title><i nz-icon type="info"></i>News</span>
</li>
```

I use the directive [nzSelected] and function:

```
isSelected(route: string): boolean {
  return route === this.router.url;
}
```

to highlight the button to the currently opened route. I have noticed a problem - this makes performance worse, because on each route change, the method 'isSelected' is launched more than 100 times.

What would be the best solution to avoid method execution so much times on each page change?

Comment: What does `isSelected` method do?

Comment: isSelected compares the route address that is currently open with the one that was received as a parameter from directive. If they match, returned is True, and so the button is highlighted.

Comment: But you've used `routerLinkActive` which is going to essentially apply the CSS class `active` if that router link is active. So you can get rid of `[nzSelected]="isSelected('/home')"` altogether and your selected `li` will still look selected(with the active css class applied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for the [**`RouterLinkActive`**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) Directive:

> Lets you add a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active.

Which is essentially what you're doing by `[nzSelected]="isSelected('/home')"`.

**`routerLinkActive`** does that out of the box for you. Get rid of `[nzSelected]="isSelected('...')"` and you should be just fine

```
<li
  nz-menu-item 
  routerLink="/home" 
  routerLinkActive="active">
  <span title><i nz-icon type="home"></i>Home</span>
</li>
<li 
  nz-menu-item
  routerLink="/news" 
  routerLinkActive="active">
  <span title><i nz-icon type="info"></i>News</span>
</li>
```

> PS: I've written a [**Medium Article**](https://medium.com/@siddajmera) about Performance Improvement in Angular Apps. Although it's mainly focused on Angular Reactive forms, the performance improvement techniques will still be pretty much. You might want to check it out [**here**](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-i-increased-the-performance-of-an-extremely-deeply-nested-angular-reactive-form-by-380-c1b18ea668db).

Answer (score 1):

your `isSelected` method is useless if you have a `routerLinkActive`.

Try this instead :

```
<li nz-menu-item [nzSelected]="homeRla?.isActive" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" #homeRla="routerLinkActive">
```

And to answer you, can use

```
changeDetectionStrategy: ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush
```

In your component decorator to limit the change detection to when **you** want it to run.